# How to set voicemail using Twiml Bins?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am doing a quick POC using Twiml Bins, I am trying to connect 2 calls and if the call is unanswered by the recipient it should go to their voicemail.

Use case:

1. User A calls my twilio no.
2. Twilio places A on hold and tries to call B.
3. If B answers, B is asked to accept or deny the call. By pressing 1 or 2 (or hang up).
4. If accepted, call connects and A and B talk.
5. If rejected, A is able to leave a voicemail to B on his cell.
6. If B does not answer, A is able to leave a voicemail to B on his cell.

I am stuck at 5 and 6. Unable to have a voicemail sent to B if either call is rejected or unanswered. The nesting of Twiml tags is getting little confusing for me. Here's what I tried so far:
PutAOnholdAndCallB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Thank you for calling please wait while I connect you.</Say>
  <Dial timeout="15" action="Callhangup">
        <Number url="AcceptorDeny">UserBPhoneNo
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

AcceptorDeny:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1" timeout="20" action="DoNothing">
    <Say>You have a call, press 1 to answer or hang-up for it to go to voicemail.</Say><Pause length="3"/><Say>Connecting</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Callhangup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>
        You have reached the voicemail.
        Please leave a message at the beep. 
        Press the star key when finished. 
    </Say>

    <Record action="DoNothing"
        method="GET" 
        maxLength="20"
        finishOnKey="*"
    />
    <Hangup />
</Response>
```

DoNothing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response />
```

Comment: did you ever get to implementing this using Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your challenge is that TwiML Bin's do not offer the level of conditional logic you need to analyze the results of the [Dial action URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) you define. You need to evaluate the value of [DialCallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus), to properly direct the **unanswered** call (or calls where the dialed party doesn't press a number to answer the call).

In those  **unanswered** cases, which are where you want to send the call to your TwiML Bin voicemail logic, `Callhangup`, you check to see if DialCallStatus (of the Dial action URL) = `no-answer` otherwise you [Hangup](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup) or return no more TwiML (since the dialed party pressed a key to answer the call, so no need to present voicemail to the caller).

The logic is documented in this Twilio Function, [Implement voicemail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/wireless/tutorials/communications-guides/implement-voicemail).

I would suggest Twilio Studio to handle this however Studio doesn't currently support the [Number URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url) feature you used for the whisper the option to the dialed party the option of accepting the call.

If you did use Studio, you would need to look into the [TwiML Redirect Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect) to add that whisper functionality into your Studio Flow. I saw a blog doing what I wrote above using Studio (without whisper) last week here, [Using Twilio To Make A Call Forwarding And Voice Messaging System](https://thedarkside.frantzmiccoli.com/how%20to/2020/04/01/twilio-how-tocall-forwarding-and-voice-messaging.html).